# how to specify JSON field to base chart on?

Tags: json, charts, jasper-reports

I have a *JasperReports* report that is based on JSON data.  I am trying to add a chart to display the values of the "chartData" array, but am not having any luck.  Here's what the JSON looks like.

```
{ "reportingData": {  "dateRange": "January 1, 2014-January 31, 2014", "name" : "Name Goes Here"  , "chartData" : [ { "name" : "Industry 1", "value" : "10" } , { "name" : "Industry 2", "value" : "20" } , { "name" : "Industry 3", "value" : "30" } , { "name" : "Industry 4", "value" : "40" } , { "name" : "Industry 5", "value" : "50" }], "pageNumber": 1, "nextPage" : "true"} }
```

When I add the chart to the report, I've tried setting `$F{chartData}` as the key expression and then `$F{name}` as the label and `$F{value}` as the value, but I get compilation errors because it can't find the fields called name or value.

I've also tried setting the key expression similar to what I do with subreports, something like this:

```
((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("chartData")
```

but still no dice.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions how I can use a JSON array with a *JasperReports*'s chart - or how I need to reformat my JSON if necessary.

== UPDATE - Still need help! ==
I'm not sure where the subDataSet element should go.  Also, I'm guessing that in the subDataset I'd want to use the chartData property rather than date range since that's the data for the chart, but what class should I use for that - still java.lang.String?  The other approach you suggested is pretty much what I was trying (see the original question) except using the chartData property rather than the reportData property which is the data set for the whole report.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions - or if anyone could post the XML for a working chart that uses a subDataset.

== UPDATE 2 - STILL NO LUCK ==
Thank you for the reply.  I still can't get this to work.  I modified your code slightly because you were using reportingData as the name of the field containing the subDataset, but that is the name of the top level of the report.  The sub-data should be using the chartData field.

Here's what I'm using in the report now.  It shows a red error indicator in the eclipse plugin next to the line about the subDataset.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version last-->
        <jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="90544f77-b050-4811-8365-51bb292ac717">
            <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="TEST_FOR_CHART"/>
            <queryString language="json">
                <![CDATA[reportingData]]>
            </queryString>
            <subDataset name="chartData" uuid="2a00961e-0d9c-4bd2-b124-c4cad2fc24c9">
                <parameter name="default_null_text" class="java.lang.String"/>
                <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
                    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
                </field>
                <field name="value" class="java.lang.String">
                    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[value]]></fieldDescription>
                </field>
            </subDataset>
            <field name="dateRange" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[dateRange]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="chartData" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[chartData]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="pageNumber" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[pageNumber]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <field name="nextPage" class="java.lang.String">
                <fieldDescription><![CDATA[nextPage]]></fieldDescription>
            </field>
            <background>
                <band splitType="Stretch"/>
            </background>
            <title>
                <band height="79" splitType="Stretch"/>
            </title>
            <pageHeader>
                <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
            </pageHeader>
            <columnHeader>
                <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
            </columnHeader>
            <detail>
                <band height="252" splitType="Stretch">
                    <pieChart>
                        <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                            <reportElement x="200" y="10" width="200" height="200" uuid="d5b01ba1-6dea-4465-b440-78b4ebf2af8d"/>
                            <chartTitle/>
                            <chartSubtitle/>
                            <chartLegend/>
                        </chart>
                        <pieDataset>
                            <keyExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("chartData")]]></keyExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[0]]></valueExpression>
                        </pieDataset>
                        <piePlot>
                            <plot/>
                            <itemLabel/>
                        </piePlot>
                    </pieChart>
                </band>
            </detail>
            <columnFooter>
                <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
            </columnFooter>
            <pageFooter>
                <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
            </pageFooter>
            <summary>
                <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
            </summary>
        </jasperReport>
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: A couple of questions/advice:
1. Can you post the errors that you are getting?
2. Your key expression looks good, but do you have a dataSource to point to that specifies the fields name and value? (I can post what this should look like if you need)
3. I then find after I have a dataset I need to have a field to point it to so your chartData would be a field you define and chartDataDataSet would be your dataset.
4. You are already getting the json data correctly to your jasper report correct? If not how are you passing it to the report initially?

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Alex.  When I add the chart to the report, the wizard that appears only allows me to choose [Main Dataset] as the dataset. If the charts work similar to subreports, I'm guessing that I want the "chartData" field to be the datasource, but I can't figure out how to do that properly.

Comment: This is the current data set that is causing a compilation error:     <pieDataset>
     <keyExpression><![CDATA[((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("chartData")]]></keyExpression>
     <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{value}]]></valueExpression>
     <labelExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></labelExpression>
    </pieDataset>

Comment: I am getting data into the main report properly.  This is how that is done:  <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="IQMoreInfo"/>
 <queryString language="json">
  <![CDATA[reportingData]]>
 </queryString>

Comment: Sorry for calling you Alex, Orwell!  I saw my post was edited by Alex and thought that was who the reply came from.  Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: Hi Erich, In regards to your first comment "I want the "chartData" field to be the datasource. You can manually add it if you look at the .jrxml source. In JasperSoft studio there is a tab at the bottom of the middle panel called "source" that will let you do this. You could do it like,
<subDataset name="chartData" uuid="2a00961e-0d9c-4bd2-b124-c4cad2fc24c9">
<field name="dateRange" class="java.lang.String">
<fieldDescription><![CDATA[dateRange]]</fieldDescription>
</field>
</subDataset>

Comment: Another thing you should try is change your key expression to the following:
((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("reportingData")

Comment: I'm still having trouble with this, Orwell.  Please see my edits to the original question - my reply was too long to post here.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would try (let me know if it doesn't work and I will edit my answer if possible).
Insert your subDataset in the .jrxml right after the  tags at the beginning and before the  tag aka before you start defining your fields. Based on the JSON you posted above I would try defining the dataset like this:

```
<subDataset name="reportingData" uuid="2a00961e-0d9c-4bd2-b124-c4cad2fc24c9">
    <parameter name="default_null_text" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="dateRange" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[dateRange]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="chartData" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[chartData]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="pageNumber" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[pageNumber]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="nextPage" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[nextPage]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
</subDataset>
```

after defining your subDataset you will also need to define a field which points to it, which you would put with the other fields (you probably already have). It doesn't matter what order these fields are in just so long as the field below is there:

```
<field name="reporting_data" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[reporting_data]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

Then when you create the chart using this dataset you will "Use a JRDatasource expression". The expression you want to use is as follows:

```
((net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JsonDataSource)$P{REPORT_DATA_SOURCE}).subDataSource("reporting_data")
```

as for the class to use I recommend keeping with java.lang.String if at all possible. I've had trouble using others and you can get errors depending on how you are passing your data to jasperPrint if you have null data there if you are using something else instead of java.lang.String.

Comment: I tried a slight variation of what you suggested with no luck.  Please see the update to the original question.